# Putting a variable into an UIAlertView - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uialertview

I created an instance of UIAlertView and named it alert, I did the title and the message, now I'm on addButtonWithTitle. I have tried doing this "Time to wake up it's (strDate)" and I've also tried "Time to wake up" + strDate.
Here is the code for the instance of the UIAlertView:

```
let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "WAKE UP"
            alert.message = "Time to wake up it's" 
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("I'm Up!")
            alert.show()
```

On the 3rd line it should say alert.message = "Time to wake up it's strDate"

strDate should be a variable

Here is my strDate

```
var strDate = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(theDatePicker.date)
```

Comment: you want `"Time to wake up it's \(strDate)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answer is right but you should use this code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WAKE UP", message:nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
var strDate = "Ok";
alert.message = "Time to wake up " + strDate;


let dismissHandler = {
    (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
    })
}

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I'm Up!", style: .Default, handler: dismissHandler))
presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    
}
```

**As per Swift documentation, You should use `+` operator to add content in a string.**

> The addition operator is also supported for String concatenation:
>
> "hello, " + "world"  // equals "hello, world"

From [Swift Programming Language - Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_108)

Comment: What is UIAlertController, should it be the name of my controller?

Comment: It's a new class introduced from iOS8. It is use to show alertView and actionsheet. So it is not your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will help you

```
alert.message = "Time to wake up it's \(strDate)"
```

Comment: I already did that it just shows an error saying `Use of unresolved identifier 'strDate'`